# react hook state is not updating on first click

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am facing problem with useState hook. I have one from (using useForm), what I want to achieve is when user click on submit button it will send form data to api and collect a response from api then update state and send that updated state as params in url redirection (props.history.push).
The only thing I stuck with is my useState hook is not updating on first click. I found similar questions but that did not solve my problem or one can say I did not understood it very well, pls help.

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect} from 'react'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import CreateProcessComponent from '../../components/ProcessComponents/CreateProcess/CreateProcessComponent.jsx'
import {createProcessApiCall} from '../../services/ProcessService'


function postData (dt, err, param){
     var new_param = JSON.stringify(param)
        const result = createProcessApiCall(new_param)
            .then(response => {
                dt(response.data.data)
                console.log(response.data.data)
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
            err(true)
          })
        }
      
    

export default function CreateProcessContainer(props){

    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm()
    const [postApiData, setApiData] = useState({})
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  
  
    const sendRequest= (data) => {
      let prm = {"ProcessName":data.processName,"ProcessDescription":data.processDescription,"Code":"null", "CreatedBy":"null"}
      postData(setApiData, setIsError, prm)
      props.history.push({pathname:'/test',state:{postApiData}})
    }


  

    return (
          <main>
            {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}
            { (!isError)  ?
            <CreateProcessComponent 
                register={register} 
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit} 
                errors={errors}
                onSubmit={sendRequest}/>
                :
                null }

            </main>

    )
}
```

in above code CreateProcessComponent is my form. pls let me know what I am doing wrong and what fixes I need to add

Comment: Which `useState` isn't updating? There are 4 of them. What is being clicked on? I see no `onClick` handlers in your code snippet. My guess is stale state in an enclosure. Is `sendRequest` passed to multiple children components? If not then I doubt it needs to be memoized.

Comment: code is abit complicated. can be simplify with just a handler sendRequest without the memoization. to debug your problem, try to breakpoint at .then of createProcessApiCall(new_param) , see if it even reaches there.. if reaches , check the dt callback is executed . maybe put a temporary useEffect to see if postApiData is updated .

Comment: @DrewReese I am updating state postApiData. In sendRequest when I try to console.log(postApiData) I am getting empty hook

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat data is getting updated on second button click and yes it is reaching to createProcessApiCall(new_param) and I am getting response from API

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat pls let me know how can I simplify my code

Comment: You can take out the `useCallback` hook as it likely doesn't need to be memoized. It at least would remove a layer of complexity and possibly make debugging easier.

Comment: @DrewReese I need to wait till I receive response from API so that, I can pass api response as param to another component at the time of redirection

Comment: `useCallback` react hook has *absolutely* zero to do with `async` functions. `sendRequest` can happily be an `async` function, awaiting anything it needs to pass on to the next function. I just don't see any benefit of wrapping  that function logic in the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: I agree with @Drew , just put postData function inside your function component and remove dt callback parameter. call the postData directly when form is submitted. when success in .then statement, setApiData directly. no need to memoize it if it is not heavy calculation.

Comment: @DrewReese and @@Kevin I'll tell you guys the flow so you can guide me easily

1: user fills the form and click on submit
2: get formdata and do some modification and send it to POST api as parameters
3: get the response from API
4: redirect user to another page using (props.history.push) with response received from api as parameters

this all should happen one single button click

Comment: @DrewReese updated the code. postApiData in props.history.push(postApiData) is empty

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat updated the code. postApiData in props.history.push(postApiData) is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`sendRequest` is updating state, but you are trying to grab the updated state for the navigation push on the next line. React state updates are asynchronous and the updated `postApiData` state value won't be available until at least a render cycle later. `postData` is also doing some asynchronous processing but it doesn't return a promise that can be awaited on.

So basically `sendRequest` fires off a `postData` call, then immediately does the navigation since this function is completely synchronous

```
const sendRequest= (data) => {
  ...
  postData(setApiData, setIsError, prm) // <-- setApiData updates state
  props.history.push({
    pathname: '/test',
    state: { postApiData } // <-- current state
  });
}
```

## Solution 1

1. Make `sendRequest` an async function and `await` a response from `postData` in a try/catch
2. If successful then continue with navigation, if promise rejects then set error in `catch`
3. Return the Promise from `postData` instead of passing state update functions

### postData

Unpack the response data and return it

```
const postData = param => {
  const new_param = JSON.stringify(param);

  return createProcessApiCall(new_param)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data.data;
    });
};
```

### CreateProcessContainer

Remove the `postApiData` state and await the response from `postData`.

```
export default function CreateProcessContainer(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const sendRequest = async (data) => {
    const prm = {
      ProcessName: data.processName,
      ProcessDescription: data.processDescription,
      Code: "null",
      CreatedBy: "null"
    };

    try {
      const postApiData = await postData(prm);
      history.push({ pathname: "/result", state: { postApiData } });
    } catch {
      setIsError(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      {isError ? (
        <div>Something went wrong ...</div>
      ) : (
        <CreateProcessComponent
          register={register}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          errors={errors}
          onSubmit={sendRequest}
        />
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

## Solution 2

1. Make post data take success & failure callbacks to handle the promise resolve/rejection
2. Pass callbacks from `sendRequest`

### postData

Unpack the response data and pass it to and invoke the success callback. Pass the failure callback to the catch block.

```
const postData = (param, success, failure) => {
  const new_param = JSON.stringify(param);

  createProcessApiCall("result data from callbacks")
    .then((response) => {
      success(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch(failure);
};
```

### CreateProcessContainer

Remove the `postApiData` state, and pass the param and success/failure callbacks to `postData`.

```
export default function CreateProcessContainer(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const sendRequest = (data) => {
    const prm = {
      ProcessName: data.processName,
      ProcessDescription: data.processDescription,
      Code: "null",
      CreatedBy: "null"
    };
    postData
      prm,
      (postApiData) => {
        history.push({ pathname: "/result", state: { postApiData } });
      },
      () => setIsError(true)
    );
  };

  return (
    <main>
      {isError ? (
        <div>Something went wrong ...</div>
      ) : (
        <CreateProcessComponent
          register={register}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          errors={errors}
          onSubmit={sendRequest}
        />
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-hook-state-is-not-updating-on-first-click]

Comment: I already solved it. I really appreciate your efforts, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const main = useRef(null);
```

```
if(main) {}
```

```
<main ref={main}>
```

PS: Haven't sense

```
    // set isMounted to false when we unmount the component
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        isMounted.current = false
      }
    }, [])
```

Your component will destroy, for what sets `isMounted`?

Answer (score 0):

Below changes solved my problem, let me know if I can improve the code

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect} from 'react'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import CreateProcessComponent from '../../components/ProcessComponents/CreateProcess/CreateProcessComponent.jsx'
import {createProcessApiCall} from '../../services/ProcessService'



    

export default function CreateProcessContainer(props){

    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm()
    const [postApiData, setApiData] = useState({})
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);


    function postData (dt, err, param){
      var new_param = JSON.stringify(param)
         createProcessApiCall(new_param)
             .then(response => {
                 dt(response.data.data)
                //  dt(response.data.data)
                 console.log(response.data.data)
           })
           .catch(e => {
             console.log(e)
             err(true)
           })
         }
       

useEffect(()=>{if (Object.keys(postApiData).length > 0)
  props.history.push({pathname:'/test',state:postApiData})},[postApiData])
  
  
  
    const sendRequest= (data) => {
      let prm = {"ProcessName":data.processName,"ProcessDescription":data.processDescription,"Code":"null", "CreatedBy":"null"}
      postData(setApiData, setIsError, prm)
    }


    return (
          <main>
            {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}
            { (!isError)  ?
            <CreateProcessComponent 
                register={register} 
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit} 
                errors={errors}
                onSubmit={sendRequest}/>
                :
                null }
            </main>

    )
}
```